# C++ code not behaving as expected (classes and containers)

Tags: c++, class, containers

Here are the inserts of my code...

main.cpp

```
void addStuff(Journey& journey)
{
  journey.addPerson("John Doe", "USA");
}

void demo()
{
  Journey journey("Sweden");
  addStuff(journey);
  std::cout << journey;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  demo();
  return 0;
}
```

Journy.cpp

```
void Journey::addPerson(const char* name, const char* nationality)
{
  add(Person(name, nationality));
}

void Journey::add(Person person)
{
  persons_.push_back(person);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Journey& journey)
{
  out << "Journey: " << journey.name_ << std::endl;

  out << "  Persons attending:" << std::endl;
  for(Journey::PersonList::const_iterator person_it =  journey.persons_.begin();
      person_it != journey.persons_.end();
      person_it++)
  {
    out << "    " << *person_it;
  }

  return out;
}
```

Person.cpp

```
Person::Person(){}

Person::Person(const char* name, const char* nationality) : name_(0), 
                                                            nationality_(0)
{
  copyString(&name_, name);
  copyString(&nationality_, nationality);
}

Person::Person(const Person& other): name_( other.name_), 
                                     nationality_( other.nationality_) {}

void Person::copyString(char** dest, const char* source)
{
  unsigned int str_len = strlen(source);
  char* str = new char[str_len+1];
  strncpy(str, source, str_len);
  str[str_len] = '\0';
  *dest = str;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Person& person)
{
  out << person.name_ << " (" << person.nationality_ << ")" << std::endl;
  return out;
}
```

However, when I try to execute the code, as a result I get:

Persons attending:
    P�� ()

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Could the problem be the scope and lifetime of variables? As I understood, a list container makes a copy of each entry, so the scope and lifetime shouldn't be the issue. I have also seen somewhere that in order for a class instance to be stored in the list, the class must have default constructor, copy constructor and an = operator overloaded. My class Person has all these characteristics.
The code I posted are just inserts that I found relevant for this issue.
If anyone could give me the slightest hint what the problem could be, it would be really appreciated.

With regards

Comment: When I beneath persons_.push_back(person); put std::cout<<persons_.back(); it prints the person as intended.

@101010
Not true as char* str = new char[str_len+1];

Comment: Your copy constructor is copying pointers but what if they don't exist? You should make a deep copy, means allocate new memory and copy the values as well. You could use your `copyString` method for that. Add a destructor where you `delete[]` your allocated memory.

Answer (score 4):

You do have a copy-constructor, which is good since you do a lot of copying. However, you only do shallow copying, i.e. copy only the pointers and not the actual contents.

This means that if you make a copy of a `Person` object (like you do when calling `Journey::add(Person person)`) then you will have *two* objects both using the same pointers to the same memory. If your destructor (if you have any) free the memory, then the memory is free'd for *both* objects, but one of the object will still have the pointers to the now free memory, leading to *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference those pointers.

You need to do *deep* copying, in other words allocate new memory and copy the contents. Or do the sensible thing and use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).